# Python: jsonschema package to validate schema and custom error messages

Tags: python, validation, jsonschema

Given this schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "account": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["id"],
            "properties": {
                "id": {"type": "number"}
            }
        },
        "name": {"type": "string"},
        "trigger": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["type"],
            "properties": {
                "type": {"type": "string"}
            }
        },
        "content": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "emails": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "minItems": 1,
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "required": ["fromEmail","subject"],
                        "properties": {
                            "fromEmail": {"type": "string", "format": "email"},
                            "subject": {"type": "string"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use `jsonschema.Draft4Validator` to validate a POSTed JSON object to check for validity, but I am having some issues trying to come up with better human readable messages from the returned errors.

Here is how I am validating:

```
from jsonschema import Draft4Validator

v = Draft4Validator(self.schema)
errors = sorted(v.iter_errors(autoresponder_workflow), key=lambda e: e.path)

if errors:
    print(', '.join(
        '%s %s %s' % (error.path.popleft(), error.path.pop(), error.message) for error in errors
    ))
```

The error message looks like:

`content emails [] is too short, trigger type None is not of type u'string'`

Im trying to create an error message that looks a little more like *Please add at least one email to your workflow," "Please ensure that all of your emails contain subject lines,", etc*

Answer (score 20):

I had the need of displaying a more detailed custom message to the user when an error occurred. I did this by adding a field to the property in the schema and then looking it up on ValidationError.

```
import json
import jsonschema


def validate(_data, _schema):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(_data, _schema)
    except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
        return e.schema.get("error_msg", e.message)


schema = {
    "title": "index",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "author",
        "description"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "author": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Name of the Author",
            "minLength": 3,
            "default": "",
            "error_msg": "Please provide a Author name"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Short description",
            "minLength": 10,
            "default": "",
            "error_msg": "Please add a short description"
        }
    }
}

data = {
    "author": "Jerakin",
    "description": ""
}
```

Comment: This is really good.  I was getting frustrated with the same issu and started thinking a field like "error_msg" would be a good addition to the jsonschema spec.  This is a decent workaround.  The only thing I would want to add is interpolation in the error message, maybe.  However, considering that this is generally used for processing incoming data (user data), this could be inherently risky.  Another option would be to make error_msg a callback.

Comment: fantastic solution.

Comment: @Jerakin will this work when main keys - `author`, `description` are missing ?

Comment: @user5319825 You might have to add a `error_msg` in the root of the schema to catch that. But, as there could be a lot of errors at that stage I think it's better return the error message to the user. I have updated my answer with a tweak to `validate()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch [ValidationError exception](http://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.0/errors/) and build a custom messages for the specific cases you want from ValidationError metadata. In this object you have:

info of the failed validator: its value and schema path
info of the failed instance: its path and value at the time of the failed validation
possible errors in subschemas
cause (errors caused by a non-validation error)

Answer (score 1):

You could try `jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError`:

```py
try:
    v = Draft4Validator(self.schema)
except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as err:
    print(err.message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this scrub function before running validate. It converts `None` to empty string as jsonschema does not like to handle `None` type. On validate it throws: `jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: None is not of type u'string'`.

```
def scrub(x):
    ret = copy.deepcopy(x)
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        for k, v in ret.items():
            ret[k] = scrub(v)
    if isinstance(x, (list, tuple)):
        for k, v in enumerate(ret):
            ret[k] = scrub(v)
    if x is None:
        ret = ''
    return ret
```

Comment: The JSON schema standard enforces this type checking, `jsonschema` just conforms to the standard. `None` (aka `"null"`) is in fact not of type `"string"`. If you want `null` to be a valid value, just set `"type": ["string", "null"]` for the object in your schema. Or use `"oneOf"` for more complicated types, and add `"null"` as one of the options.